# Unable to programatically login to a website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

So I am trying to login programatically (python) to https://www.datacamp.com/users/sign_in using my email & password.

I have tried 2 methods of login. One using requests library & another using selenium (code below). Both time facing [403] issue.

Could someone please help me login programatically to it ?

Thank you !

Using Requests library.

```
import requests; r = requests.get("https://www.datacamp.com/users/sign_in"); r (which gives <response [403]>)
```

Using Selenium webdriver.

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)
 driver.get("https://www.datacamp.com/users/sign_in")
 driver.find_element_by_id("user_email") # there is supposed to be form element with id=user_email for inputting email
```

Answer (score 1):

Implicit wait at least should have worked, like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
url = "https://www.datacamp.com/users/sign_in"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id("user_email").send_keys("test@dsfdfs.com")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#new_user>button[type=button]").click()
```

**BUT**

The real issue is the the site uses anti-scraping software.
If you open Console and go to request itself you'll see:
[image]

It means that the site blocks your connection even before you try to login.
Here is similar question with different solutions: [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

Not all answers will work for you, try different approaches suggested.

With Firefox you'll have the same issue (I've already checked).

Comment: Thank you ! I understand the issue now. Is it also the case that the website is blocking the login using requests library ? It seems so. Is there a way to work around it ?

Comment: I added the issue with multiple suggestions on how it can be fixed. Frankly, it is not an easy task,  I'd start from the easiest one https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/12730112 and then would try the approved answer. But do not forget to make a backup of your chromedriver before trying it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a wait after `driver.get("https://www.datacamp.com/users/sign_in")` before  `driver.find_element_by_id("user_email")` to let the page loaded.
Try something like `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user_email')))`

Comment: Thats not the issue. I forgot to add wait in the code snippet I shared here, but original code had it. Not able to login even with requests library.